# 'the specified network name is no longer available' for mapped drive folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, networking, mapped-drive

Recently started getting the following error when trying to access the contents of a folder on particular mapped drive. The program runs in Visual studio 2010 and the odd thing is that there are two folders on that drive in the same directory and the error only occurs for one folder. I checked the properties of each folder and it seems to match so not sure what could possibly be the issue.

```
IOEXception was unhandled. The specified network name is no longer available.
```

The folder in question here is Z:\Output\FTransferBACKUP but the one accessible is Z:\Output\TTransferBACKUP.

```
 For Each item In folderList
        Dim fileLists As String() = Directory.GetFiles(item)
        Try
            For i As Integer = 0 To fileLists.Count - 1
                Try
                    Dim fileobj As New FileInfo(fileLists(i))
                    Dim filename As String = fileobj.Name
                    Dim CutOffDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
                         ....
```

the folderlist contains the paths to the various folders I access for archiving. 
eg. Z:\Output\TTransferBACKUP, Z:\Output\FTransferBACKUP, E:\Output\T2TransferBACKUP, E:\Output\F2TransferBACKUP. The E drive is  a local drive on that server.